# acting like a switch between two sockets with python

Tags: python, networking, virtualization, packet-sniffers

am very new to this community

192.168.10.159:35621 communicates with 192.168.10.40:9000 where i have act like a switch between two ports validate the inbound and outbound data and send on successful validation i have send same to respected IP's

is there any sniffers or virtual network tools to help me on this
please suggest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try **ncat** like this:

```
ncat -o dump -l 192.168.10.159 35621 --sh-exec "ncat 192.168.10.40 9000"
```

If your distribution doesn't come with ncat or you are on windows you can get it from 
[Nmap download page](http://nmap.org/download.html). No installation required, just drop it somewhere convenient.